# facebook connect blank pop up on chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook Connect to my site using the javsacript SDK.

The codes are like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
         FB.init({appId: '**********', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

         /* All the events registered */
         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
             // do something with response
             login();
         });
         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
             // do something with response
             logout();
         });

         FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
             if (response.session) {
                 // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                 login();
             }
         });

         (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
     };
</script>
```

then the button `<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>`

This works fine in Firefox; but in chrome, the facebook pop-up to "allow" the app to access fb ends up with a black page title "XD Proxy". Can anyone help me figure it out??

Comment: open facebook in chrome, logout, try it again

Comment: same thing.. still not resolved. :/

Answer (score 12):

I was recently having trouble with a website I was working on and Chrome leaving the Facebook login page open.  Title of the popup was "XD Proxy".  If I closed the popup manually, I was logged into the site.

I found that the problem occurred when I had the website installed as a Chrome App from the Chrome store.  **Once I uninstalled the Chrome App, the Facebook login worked perfectly.**  This just started happening a few weeks ago for me so I went to the Chrome App store to see if I needed to update the app settings.  I changed the version number and uploaded a few new images that the Chrome App Store now requires but it did not fix the problem.  As soon as I installed the App in Chrome, the Facebook login stopped working again.  I uninstalled....works perfectly.

The Chrome App Store lets you package up websites as a hosted app so the only thing you do to get in in the store is upload a manifest file with information about the website and a few images.

Comment: OH MY GOD I LOVE YOU!  I've been plagued with this for literally MONTHS. I had finally decided my facebook account was just corrupt or something since nobody else I talked to experienced the problem.  This fixed it immediately. Can I have your babies?!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. I can't believe something as simple as an app that simply links to Facebook can cause such a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize what Doug said, and explain what worked for me:

I had the exact same problem. I also had Facebook installed as a Chrome App. By simply deleting that app, the blank pop-up problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem as Doug and David. Uninstalling Facebook APP fixed this.